# Что вызывает ошибку?

Tags: python, django

Я попытался расширить модель User, унаследовав AbstractUser:

models.py

```
class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='teacher_subject')
    person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'education.Teacher'
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('name','surname','subject')

class TeacherChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('name','surname','subject')
```

admin.py

```
class TeacherUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = TeacherRegistrationForm
    form = TeacherChangeForm
    model = Teacher
    list_display = ['name','surname','subject']

admin.site.register(Teacher, TeacherUserAdmin)
```

И когда я пытаюсь создать миграции, я получаю ошибку

```
courses.Course.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
courses.Course.students: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
courses.File.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
courses.Image.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
courses.Text.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
courses.Video.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

Что мне с этим делать?

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в settings.py в переменной AUTH_USER_MODEL. Попробуйте указать ее полный путь <app_name>.<user.py / model.py>.Teacher. Возможно поможет

Comment: @Betensis Неа, это уже обычный ValueError: `String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаляете все миграции, базу. Копируете мой код, вставляете к себе. Делаете миграции.

```
# app/models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app.models import Teacher


class TeacherInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Teacher
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'teachers'


class UserTeacher(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (TeacherInline,)

admin.site.register(User, UserTeacher)
```

`settings.py` у вас правильный, `forms.py` к вашему вопросу не имеет отношения.

По всей видимости ошибка конкретно в предыдущих миграциях.
Пример запускал - работает. (обратите внимание, что я немного упростил (убрал) одно поле из вашего тичера)

Comment: А как все миграции и базу удалить? Какой командой?

Comment: Можно просто руками взять и удалить в папке миграций. И базу из файлов - если она локально.